# How come getComputedTextLength() gives different results in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using getComputedTextLength() on SVG text elements to wrap text lines. However, I get different results in Firefox and Chrome. Here is an example that gives different results using Chromium 18.0 and Firefox 12.0: http://jsfiddle.net/cBSp4/2/

How come the result is different and, more importantly, is it fixable?

(Values from getBBox() seem to be alright, so I'm using that as a workaround at the moment).

Comment: a jsfiddle would be useful :)

Comment: sure thing, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/cBSp4/2/

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question, but I made a workaround by adding spaces around the string I want to measure (" text ") and then subtract the calculated length of two spaces ("  ").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be fixed in Firefox 25 when the [big SVG text rewrite goes live](http://mcc.id.au/blog/2013/07/firefox-svg-text-improvements).

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Then I can safely limit my spaces hack to older Firefox versions only.